# Finding string inside variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a string inside a variable. The problem is that it doesn't look for a unique string.
For example, a have a variable with the following values:

```
$mystring = "p,pp,m,g";
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
<?php 
    $find="pp";
    if(strstr($mystring, $find)==true){
        echo "found"; 
    } 
?>
```

The problem is: when I'm looking for pp, it also returns "p" as a result.
How can I avoid this kind of error?
I'm using it to check the sizes of a item on an ecommerce website and I'm struggling to get it right.

Any ideas?!

Comment: You don't need to check `strstr($mystring, $find) == true`.

Comment: I tried you code. It is working fine for me. It echo found if pp is found. If i remove pp from $mystring, it does not echo anything!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Make sure you use the !== operator.

```
echo strpos($mystring, $find) !== false ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Comment: @user1541940 then you need to use preg_match() and specify that you want no p next to it

Comment: right, it's harder than I thought...I'm thinking in just changing the sizes from letters to numbers...thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
$mystring = "p,pp,m,g";
$str      = explode(",",$mystring);

$find     = "/^pp$/";
foreach($str as $val){
   if(preg_match($find, $val)){
       echo "found => ".$val; 
   }else{
       echo "not found";
   }
}
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Same problem here...it works but it returns true for p or pp because "pp" also has a "p"...got it?!

Comment: each , separated need to match ? OR it is a single string ?

Comment: each, separated need to match.

Comment: Edited the code please check it. Please note the `^` and `$` in find string. ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use transformating to array and search as array's element:

```
$mystring = "p,pp,m,g";
$arr = explode(',',$mystring);
if (in_array('p',$arr,true)) {echo "found";}
```

Or (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php: "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead") you can write

```
if (strpos($mystring,'pp')!==false) {echo 'found';} else {echo 'not found';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the values and used the same strstr function to avoid similar letters problem.